# Do I need the code deploy step in aws code pipeline for a static s3 website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I created a repo in Code Commit for a static s3 website
Then I created a CodePipeline and configured the code build part.
There I set the Build Spec file with the some basic commands:
build and then copy the files in the s3 bucket.
The third step the Code Deploy I'm not sure why it's needed.
When I run it it gets stuck for an hour.
I did disable it and the site was deployed just fine.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You can disable it if it's running fine without it. It's up to you if you want it or not. You can do the same using codeDeploy and skip the CodeBuild part or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the CodeDeploy part if it is working fine for you. Or you can skip the CodeBuild step and use appspec.yml to deploy the static website onto S3.

You have to use either of the steps to make it work, you can't skip both the steps.

CodeDeploy part is present in the CodePipeline in case you need to deploy it on your EC2 fleet or Autoscaling Group after you have built the artifacts. If not needed, just skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Codepipeline has three stages source->codeBuild->codeDeploy. According to Amazon you must use atleast two stages of the Codepipeline, You cannot skip the first stage (i.e source) but you choose any one or both from the remaining. For your use case source and CodeBuild stages are enough you don't need codedeploy. Just remove the codeDeploy stage.